# Ajax post and Fetch Post

Tags: javascript, json

The system that works by using "ajax post" does not work when I use "fetch post".

I've been dealing with this problem for a few days, thank you very much, if anyone can help.

```
var json_data = {};
json_data.saveitem = JSON.stringify(OtherJson);

$.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "post",
            data: json_data,
            async:false,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }

        });
```

The message returned at the end of the transaction is as follows;

```
{"errno":0,"errdesc":"","success":true,"result":[]}
```

That's okay, everything works fine, but when I do it with the method below, "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" gives this error.
There is the ".catch" part below in the line it points to.

```
fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            body: json_data,
            headers: {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   headers: {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
```

Remove **;** next to **application/json** and replace with **,** I think so?